# psql -f command not working with filename path specified

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I think the command psql is not working but can't find the reason behind. 
I've been struggling for the last 3 hours on this.

Very new to PostgreSQL, I set up the environment on my laptop and the code below seems to be working correctly.

[image: screenshot of console]

But when I try to use the psql command and run the command

```
postgres=# psql -f C:\Users\36922\Desktop\products.sql inventory postgres;
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid command \Users.
```

[image: screenshot of error]

I would like psql to work, but it does not. Would you have any suggestion?

Comment: Looks like you're already inside psql when you're trying that command. You need to be on a regular terminal and then it should work.

Comment: Hi @Hitobat. - do you mean I should be working from another terminal, like Windows Command Prompt ?

Comment: Yes, something like command prompt should work. Alternatively if you want to run from inside psql, you can try \i command to run a file. e.g. `\i C:\Users\36922\Desktop\products.sql`

Answer (score 1):

As @Hitobat mentioned in his comment, this command should be ran outside of the PSQL terminal in the WCP or PowerShell.